# How do I copy files?

Tags: drupal, file-copying

I need to copy a file from one folder to another folder. How can I implement this in Drupal. Give me some ideas with working examples.

Comment: For which version of Drupal are you interested? There are functions in Drupal 7 that were not defined in Drupal 6.

Answer (score 5):

Second result on Google for "file copy, drupal"...
[file_copy()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/function/file_copy/6)

> Copies a file to a new location.
>
> This is a powerful function that in
>   many ways performs like an advanced
>   version of [copy()](http://php.net/copy).
>
> - Checks if $source and $dest are valid
>     and readable/writable.
> - Performs a file
>     copy if $source is not equal to $dest.
> - If file already exists in $dest either
>     the call will error out, replace the
>     file or rename the file based on the
>     $replace parameter.